# Ios file download not working

Tags: ios, file, download, angular5

I face a problem with IOS file download.
I'm trying to make the user download a file when he click on a link. I create a blob and make a click on the link.

It's working fine on desktop but not on mobile...

```
            let blob = new Blob([success], { type: success.type });
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, dd.filename);
        } else {
          let a  = document.createElement('a');
          let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          a.href = url;
          a.download = dd.filename;
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
          this.flashService.success('Dernières consultations', 'Ce document a été téléchargé');
          this.downloaded.emit(this.document);
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: In what way does it fail on mobile? Does it give a specific error message? Does it report success but no file appears? Does it summon Yog Sothoth?

Comment: https://www.noelshack.com/2018-09-7-1520167439-image.png

It just open this and it dosent download the file or preview it like it does on desktop

Comment: The default behavior on desktop is download file without moving from the page

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.

```
{ type: success.type }
```

I had the wrong type in this variable that was the reason. Mobile navigator failed to recognize the file type